# __str__ returned non-string (type list)

Tags: json, django, django-models, django-views

I am having a django app in which I am storing the json variable.I have stored the json variable through admin and I am trying to print it in shell.My main aim is to pass this variable to a webpage with ajax method.But first when I was trying to print it in shell I get this error

```
__str__ returned non-string (type list)
```

My models.py is of this form

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from jsonfield import JSONField


# Create your models here.


class newgrid(models.Model):
    data = JSONField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.data
```

My JSON variable is of this form

```
[{"col":1,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":2,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":3,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":4,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":1,"row":2,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":2,"row":2,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":3,"row":2,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":4,"row":2,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":1,"row":3,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":2,"row":3,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":3,"row":3,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":4,"row":3,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":5,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":1}]
```

In shell I ran following commands

```
from testforweb.models import newgrid
newgrid.objects.all()
```

It initially returned this

```
<QuerySet [<newgrid: newgrid object (1)>]>
```

But then I added

```
 def __str__(self):
        return self.data
```

Just to see the actual JSON variable.But I am getting the error
How to see the actual JSON variable which I inserted through admin coz I need to send it to webpage as it is

**Edit 1**

```
My updated models.py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from jsonfield import JSONField
import simplejson as json

# Create your models here.


    class newgrid(models.Model):
        data = JSONField()
        def __str__(self):
            json.dumps(self.data)
```

Comment: Sorry for wrong tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__str__` function **must return** a string:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return json.dumps(self.data)
```

Comment: I tried with  `newgrid.objects.get(pk=1)` but still i get`<newgrid: [{`

Comment: How can I avoid that newgrid and just get the variable

Comment: Sorry to irritate you but when I pass the variable to webpage it is perfect as it is in database

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Did you try that get in a django shell mode? If so - it will be using the `__repr__` method. If you override that - you'll change what you see in the shell.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON field will actually decode the JSON into native python types (lists and dictionaries).

The `__str___` method is always expected to return a string.
If you want a string representation of the json, you should use `json.dumps(self.data)` or similar to serialise the data field as the return value of `__str__`.

Comment: So replace  `return self.data` with `json.dumps(self.data)` ?

Comment: Yes - that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
   def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.data)
```

Instead of

```
   def __str__(self):
        return json.dumps(self.data)
```